# Unexpected output with cons()

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cons

I am from an imperative background but these days trying my hands on LISP (Common LISP)

I read [here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/310/pwfong/Lisp/1/tutorial1.html)  about `cons` that

> (cons x L): 
>   Given a LISP object x and a list L, evaluating (cons x L) creates a list containing x followed by the elements in L.

When I intentionally did not use a list as the second argument i.e when I used

`(cons 'a 'a)` I expected an error but whoa! I got `(A . A)`.

What have I missed and what is  `(A . A)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Cons` constructs a "cons cell".  This has nothing to do with lists at first.  A cons cell is a pair of two values.  A cons cell is represented in written form by a "dotted pair", e.g. `(A . B)`, which holds the two values `'A` and `'B`.

The two places in a cons cell are called "car" and "cdr".  You can visualize such a cons cell as a bisected block:

```
  car   cdr
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
```

In Lisp, a value can also be a reference to something else, for example, another cons cell:

```
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
|  A  |   --------> |  B  |  C  |
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
```

This would be represented in "dotted pair" form as `(A . (B . C))`.  You can continue like this:

```
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
|  A  |   --------> |  B  |   --------> |  C  |  D  |
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
```

This is `(A . (B . (C . D)))`.  As you can see, in such a structure, the values are always in the `car` of a cons cell, and the `cdr` points to the rest of the structure.  An exception is the last value, which is in the last `cdr`.  We do not need this exception, though:  there is a special value `NIL` in Lisp, which denotes "nothing".  By putting `NIL` into the last `cdr`, you have a handy sentinel value, and *all* your values are in the `car`s:

```
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
|  A  |   --------> |  B  |   --------> |  C  |   --------> |  D  | NIL |
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
```

This is how a list is constructed in Lisp.  Since `(A . (B . (C . (D . NIL))))` is a bit unwieldy, it can also be represented simply as `(A B C D)`.  `NIL` is also called the empty list `()`; these are exchangable notations for the same thing.

Now you can see why `(cons x list)` returns another list.  `Cons` simply constructs another cons cell with `x` in the `car` and a reference to `list` in the `cdr`:

```
+-----+-----+
|  X  |   --------> list
+-----+-----+
```

and if `list` is `(A B)`, it works out as:

```
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
|  X  |   --------> |  A  |   --------> |  B  | NIL |
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
```

So, `(cons x '(a b))` evaluates to `(x a b)`.

Lists are just one very common use of cons cells.  You can also construct arbitrary trees from cons cells, or circular lists, or any directed graph, actually.

Answer (score 1):

`'a` is a lisp atom and `(A . A)` is a degenerate list called a [cons cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) or "dotted pair". Since you didn't pass a list for argument `L` in `(cons x L)` you got back a cell.

Answer (score 1):

(CONS x L)

Given x and L, CONS returns a new cons cell with x as the CAR of that cell and L as the CDR of that cell.

Lists are linked chains of cons cells.

```
CL-USER 141 > (sdraw '(a b c))

[*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]---> NIL
  |        |        |
  v        v        v
  A        B        C

CL-USER 142 > (sdraw (cons 'foo '(a b c)))

[*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]---> NIL
  |        |        |        |
  v        v        v        v
 FOO       A        B        C
```

If CONS gets two symbols as an argument it looks like this:

```
CL-USER 143 > (sdraw (cons 'foo 'bar))

[*|*]---> BAR
  |
  v
 FOO
```